# How to replace current screen with a screen from the parent navigator in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a nested navigator in my application like this:

```
StartStackNavigator:
   Splash: screen
   SignUp: screen
   HomeModal: HomeModalStackNavigator:
              Add: AddStackNavigator:
                        SelectCategory: screen
                        AddProduct: screen
              Home: HomeTabBarNavigator:
                          Profile: screen
                          LogOut: screen
```

When I am in the "LogOut" screen, I want to replace "SignUp" screen after a successful logout.
I use this:

```
props.navigation.replace("SignUp")
```

This command raise an Error which says:

```
Error: There is no route defined for key SignUp. Must be one of: "Add","Home"
```

But when I use "navigate" instead of "replace", it navigate to "SignUp" screen without any problem. I don't want to use "navigate" because the user can get back to the "LogOut" screen by pressing back button.

How can I send the user to the "SginUp" screen after logout process and remove all previous screens from the navigation stack?

Comment: is this react-navigation or react-native-navigation are we talking about?

Comment: react-navigation package